# How to organize multiple projects in an ASP.NET CORE solution like DDD?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code

How to create a solution of .net core?
For example:
1 Web Project
3 Lib Projects

How to create it without Visual Studio?

Using VS Code or Sublime Text?

Comment: What operating system are you using? What shell are you using?

Comment: Windows.. But I am asking to go to linux and there is no VS Studio

Answer (score 10):

If you have dotnet core installed just create a root folder for your solution. Then open terminal in root folder and type for a mvc project:

```
dotnet new mvc -o SolutionName.Web
```

remember -o parameter creates a folder for new project and if it was -n project was going to be created in the folder you are in.

and for class library project

```
dotnet new classlib -o SolutionName.Library

cd SolutionName.Web
```

this line to add reference to use this library.

```
dotnet add reference ../SolutionName.Library/SolutionName.Library.csproj
```

get to root folder again

```
cd..

dotnet new sln -n SolutionName
```

we talked about -n. After we created solution we will add projects to solution.

```
dotnet sln add SolutionName.Web/SolutionName.Web.csproj

dotnet sln add SolutionName.Library/SolutionName.Library.csproj

dotnet build
```

if you are using vs code just type

```
code .
```

in the root of solution in terminal and you will start coding.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example project referenced from Microsofts Docs website (https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb).  As you can see, inside of the src folder they break up the 'solution' into three 'projects', 'web', 'infrastructure' and 'applicationCore'.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it using PowerShell and the [`dotnet` command line interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/).

Create directories for the Web and Lib projects.

```
New-Item -Type Directory Web             
New-Item -Type Directory Lib01           
New-Item -Type Directory Lib02           
New-Item -Type Directory Lib03
```

Create the Web Project

```
cd .\Web\                                
dotnet new --lang C# --type Web          
cd ..
```

Create the three Lib projects.

```
cd .\Lib01\                              
dotnet new --lang C# --type Lib          
cd ..                                    

cd .\Lib02\                              
dotnet new --lang C# --type Lib          
cd ..                                     

cd .\Lib03\                              
dotnet new --lang C# --type Lib          
cd ..
```

Comment: Thanks friend, I already knew that... 

But how do I make the references between the projects so that the assemblies communicate with each other?